# Why can't I use - in field names?

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I'm just trying to clear a text field, which has never been a problem for me.
However, this is NOT working:

```
<html>
<body>

<form name="form">

<input type="text" name="input-field" value="Value" />

<input type="button" name="clear" value="Clear field" onclick="document.form.input-field.value = ''"; />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

But if I rename "input-field" to "inputfield" and onclick to onclick="document.form.inputfield.value = ''"; ... Then it works fine.

However... Removing the "-" from the field name, is not an option in my case (long explanation).

So, how do I clear a text field, containing a "-"???

Comment: You should use `id` instead of `name` when you want to get an element with javascript.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because it's not a valid JavaScript identifier. However, you can use the following instead:

```
document.form['input-field'].value
```

It's for the same reason you can't declare a variable using `var my-var`. On the other hand, if you have an `object`, such as `form` with several keys, you can access its properties as if it was an associative array:

```
var form = {
  "input-field": 20,
  otherKey: 30
};
form.input-field; // Error
form.otherKey; // OK
form['input-field']; // OK
```

#### References:

- **[Identifier Names and Identifiers](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6)** (ECMAScript Language Specification)
- [**Objects as associative arrays**](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html)

Answer (score 6):

`-` is not a valid character in an identifier because, for example

```
document.form.input-field;
```

is interpreted as

```
document.form.input - field;
```

Of course you can remedy the problem by using the square bracket notation:

```
document.form["input-field"];
```